# VueJS Double and Single Quotes Issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

While parsing a string having double quotes or single quotes, I'm getting the following error:

> Unexpected token in JSON.

How do I parse and bind to a Vue.js variable?

#### PHP

```php
$arr = array();
$arr[0]['description'] = "Some Description\"";
print_r(json_encode($arr));
```

#### JavaScript (Vue.js)

```javascript
this.description = JSON.parse(data); // Getting the error on this line
```

Comment: show some code, where you get error

Comment: could you please tell me whether it is working or not? In mine it was working as expected

Comment: Can you log data? And show the full error, because the exact character reported gives a big clue to the actual problem

Comment: when I am checking(either console or alert) "abc" value it is giving output as "abc"" in alert. could you please check once again??

Comment: Could you please go through this fiddle once. https://jsfiddle.net/n7tf94j8/

Comment: whatever the code i am writing it won't remove the "" from your string..

Comment: The problem is while parsing the stringified json.

Comment: when i print "abc" value it is printing <abc"> you want this only right?

Comment: To bind to any variable in VueJS, i need to parse the json data. I cannot bind stringified json directly to a variable. So, i'll need to use JSON.parse where i'm getting the issue.

Comment: What is the value of `data`?

Comment: data is the json encoded array obtained from PHP script.

Comment: could you please write that data value once?

Comment: data = [{"description":"Some Value\""}]; let parsed = JSON.parse(data); //This gives an Error

Comment: I have edited answer could you please just check once whether it is working or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var jsonData = '{ "name":"John", "birth":"1986-12-14", "city":"New York"}';
this.description = JSON.parse(text);
```

Comment: This will work unless i add a " or ' in one of the values.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit lengthy. But the following worked for me (if you have an array then you can loop through each index).

```
var test = {"description": "somevalues\""}; // Like you mentioned in data
test["description"] = test["description"].replace(/\"/g, '\'');
var newTest = JSON.stringify(test);
//console.log("hello ");
var abc = JSON.parse(newTest);
console.log(typeof(abc));
abc["description"] = abc["description"].replace(/\'/g, '"');
console.log(abc);
```